# C# XMSFactoryFactory MessageListener IMessage contains "\0" every other character

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, message-listener

I've inherited a C# application that reads from an MQ queue using XMSFactoryFactory and MessageListener to obtain messages. This application was working fine until we recently updated to the latest version of the IBM XMS client. Messages came in and were read without incident. However, since we updated which XMS client we used things changed. I am not necessarily blaming the client just stating the fact that things changed when we switched. Anyways...the application was found to be obtaining the messages with a leading "??" followed by "\0" after each character (when viewed in Quick Watch while debugging). So the XML message ends up looking like this (I shortened the message):

> ??\0<  \0?\0x\0m\0l\0 \0v\0e\0r\0s\0i\0o\0n\0=\0\"\01\0.\00\0\"\0 \0e\0n\0c\0o\0d\0i\0n\0g\0=\0\"\0U\0T\0F\0-\08\0\"\0?\0>\0

Obviously an encoding issue of some sort. However, I cannot seem to figure out what needs to change in how we connect to the queue in order for the encoding to be addressed so we can clearly process the message.

The class that includes the code that listens to the queue has code like below:

```
    private IConnection MQConnection { get; set; }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            LoadMQMessages();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex, string.Format("Exception occured while processing MQ Messages. Details- {0}", ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (this.MQConnection != null)
            {
                this.MQConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadMQMessages()
    {
        CreateMQConnection();
        this.MQConnection.Start();
        ReadMQMessage();
        this.MQConnection.Stop();
    }

    private void CreateMQConnection()
    {
        IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ).CreateConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, ConfigurationHelper.MQServerName);
        connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, ConfigurationHelper.MQServerPortNumber);
        connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, ConfigurationHelper.MQQueueManagerName);
        connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, ConfigurationHelper.MQChannelName);
        connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.USERID, ConfigurationHelper.MQUserId);

        this.MQConnection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection(null, null);
        LogInfo("Connected to MQ successfully.");

        this.MQConnection.ExceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(OnExceptionOccurred);
    }

    private void OnExceptionOccurred(Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex, string.Format("MQ Connection Issue. Message - {0}", ex.Message));
    }

    private void ReadMQMessage()
    {
        using (var session = this.MQConnection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge))
        using (var iDest = session.CreateQueue(ConfigurationHelper.MQQueueName))
        using (var consumer = session.CreateConsumer(iDest))
        {
            consumer.MessageListener = new MessageListener(OnMessageReceived);
            //We are making the main thread to sleep so that it would not die immediately it receives a message. 
            //It should be alive for the configured time.
            Thread.Sleep(ConfigurationHelper.TaskSleepDuration);
        }
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(IBM.XMS.IMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            ReadMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex, string.Format("Exception at OnMessageReceived - {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }

    public void Interrupt()
    {
        var thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

        if (thread.IsAlive)
        {
            try
            {
                thread.Abort();
                thread.Join();
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
            {
                Thread.ResetAbort();
                LogError(ex, string.Format("Exception while Interrupt - {0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReadMessage(IBM.XMS.IMessage message)
    {
        if (message is IBytesMessage)
        {
            IBytesMessage bytesMessage = (IBytesMessage)message;
            ReadBytesMessage(bytesMessage);
            message.Acknowledge();
        }
        else if (message is ITextMessage)
        {
            ITextMessage textMessage = (ITextMessage)message;
            ReadTextMessage(textMessage);
            message.Acknowledge();
        }
        else
        {
            LogError(new Exception(string.Format("Cannot Read the MQ Message because the message is not of type ITextMessage or IBytesMessage. JMSMessageID {0} Type {1}", message.JMSMessageID, message.GetType())));
        }
    }
```

It is in the method ReadMessage that the IMessage is found to be of type ITextMessage and then we can clearly see that the message looks like what I quoted above.

Supposedly the application that drops messages on the queue has not change and the MQ team has told us there have been no changes on their end. So that leaves the application I've inherited.

I've tried setting the WMQ_CCSID to various different values and nothing seemed to have changed. So I am obviously missing something.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest 1. you stop the reader app and after a message is on the queue grab a amqsbcg dump of the queue.  This will show you things like CCSID of the message, as well as what the message looks like before the application reads it.  2. does revering back to a older version fix the problem, this would help to eliminate the sending app causing the problem.

Comment: I would be good to also know the previous version of MQ XMS client you had as well as the new one, you said latest, but can be more specific (9.0.1.0 or 8.0.0.5, etc).

Comment: I'll get the version tomorrow. The CCSID says it is 1208 when I view the Consumer's properties

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?  If not do you have any further details that you can add to help us provide an answer.